# how to change csv table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pivot

**What I have?**

I have got a csv file look like that:

```
------------------------------------------
|      |         | 2017 | 2018 | 2019
|   x  | England |  70  |  80  |  90
|      |  param1 |  20  |  30  |  40
|      |  param2 |  25  |  35  |  45
|      |  param3 |  25  |  15  |   5
|   y  | England |  60  |  50  |  60
|      |  param1 |  10  |  25  |  10
|      |  param2 |  20  |  25  |  20
|      |  param3 |  30  |  0   |  30
|   x  |   US    |  10  |  20  |  30
|      |  param1 |  3   |  5   |  10
|      |  param2 |  3   |  10  |  10
|      |  param3 |  4   |  5   |  10
|   y  |   US    |  60  |  50  |  60
|      |  param1 |  10  |  25  |  10
|      |  param2 |  20  |  25  |  20
|      |  param3 |  30  |  0   |  30
...
...
...
------------------------------------------
```

**What I want to get?**

I would like to get a dataframe like this:
for each value of param(i) I want a row

```
------------------------------------------
country | type | param | year | value 
England |  x   | param1| 2017 |  20
England |  x   | param1| 2018 |  30
England |  x   | param1| 2019 |  40
England |  x   | param2| 2017 |  25
England |  x   | param2| 2018 |  35
England |  x   | param2| 2019 |  45
England |  x   | param3| 2017 |  25 
England |  x   | param3| 2018 |  15
England |  x   | param3| 2019 |  5
England |  y   | param1| 2017 |  10
England |  y   | param1| 2018 |  25
England |  y   | param1| 2019 |  10
England |  y   | param2| 2017 |  20
England |  y   | param2| 2018 |  25
England |  y   | param2| 2019 |  20
England |  y   | param3| 2017 |  30
England |  y   | param3| 2018 |   0 
England |  y   | param3| 2019 |  30
...
...
...
------------------------------------------
```

note that I don't want the values of the county row

**what I have thought to do?**

1. first to fill up the x/y type
2. delete the rows with country and add a column called 'county' with the country name
3. use pivot for change the table to get the right df

**What are my questions?**

1. how can I fill up the type easily with pandas?
2. how to add the right county to the right rows?
3. can I use pandas pivot to get what I want or there is a better way?

**Thanks**

Comment: Can you paste a link to your input datafile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `reset_index` then `melt`:

```
param_list = ['param1','param2','param3']
s=(df.rename_axis(['country','type'])
       .reset_index()
    )

mask=s['type'].isin(param_list)
s['country'] = s['type'].mask(mask).ffill()
out = s[mask].melt(['country','type'], var_name='year')
```

Output:

```
    country    type  year  value
0   England  param1  2017     20
1   England  param2  2017     25
2   England  param3  2017     25
3   England  param1  2017     10
4   England  param2  2017     20
5   England  param3  2017     30
6        US  param1  2017      3
7        US  param2  2017      3
8        US  param3  2017      4
9        US  param1  2017     10
10       US  param2  2017     20
11       US  param3  2017     30
12  England  param1  2018     30
13  England  param2  2018     35
14  England  param3  2018     15
15  England  param1  2018     25
16  England  param2  2018     25
17  England  param3  2018      0
18       US  param1  2018      5
19       US  param2  2018     10
20       US  param3  2018      5
21       US  param1  2018     25
22       US  param2  2018     25
23       US  param3  2018      0
24  England  param1  2019     40
25  England  param2  2019     45
26  England  param3  2019      5
27  England  param1  2019     10
28  England  param2  2019     20
29  England  param3  2019     30
30       US  param1  2019     10
31       US  param2  2019     10
32       US  param3  2019     10
33       US  param1  2019     10
34       US  param2  2019     20
35       US  param3  2019     30
```